# decimal value to rgb and back to decimal

Tags: javascript, rgb

I have a color in decimal form and need to transform it into rgb and back to de, so I used this to do so:

```
var currentcolor = 0xffd100;

const rgb_format = (c) => {
  var newrgb = {r: (c & 0xff0000) >> 16,
                g: (c & 0x00ff00) >> 8,
                b: (c & 0x0000ff)}

  return newrgb;
};

var rgb = rgb_format(currentcolor);

const decimal_format = (newrgb) => {
  let decimal = (newrgb.r << 16) + (newrgb.g << 8) + (newrgb.b);

  console.log(decimal);

  return decimal;
};

color.color = decimal_format(rgb);
```

Thing is, I have a rgb editor with sliders for each value(r, g, b). And they work as they should, but when the value is 16 or less in `r` the other sliders(g, b) stop changing the color of the component I am editing the color of.

Same happens when `r` and `b` are 0 and `g` is greater than 16. In this case, g changes the color to red while it is less than 16, and when it's greater than 16 it doesn't display color.
Here is a gif to show my problem:
[color-editing-problem-gif](https://pasteboard.co/J26H8eZ.gif)
or 
[alternate](https://imgur.com/HdsaNb0)

Comment: I get "image not found" when I try to view the image.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder added a new link, see if it works for you

Comment: Yes, that link works. Whatever the problem is, it doesn't seem to be in the code in the question. I [did a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/n7k3wd02/) that loops through `0x000000` through `0xffffff` and converts from decimal to rgb and back using your code. The round-trip always works.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder hmm..., weird, I am also displaying the color like this: style="background: #{currentcolor.toString(16)};", I don't know if that has anything to do with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...I am also displaying the color like this: `style="background: #{currentcolor.toString(16)};`

That won't work correctly. Consider the color 1092 decimal (0x000444). If `currentcolor` has that value, `currentcolor.toString(16)` results in `444`. `#444` is **not** the same as `#000444` in CSS, `#444` is the color `#444444`. Similarly, the color 65535 (0x00FFFF) will result in `#ffff`, which is an invalid CSS color (they must be three or six digits, not four).

To output the color correctly, you need to pad the start of the string:

```
style="background: #{currentcolor.toString(16).padStart(6, "0")}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works perfect now! The sliders were not the problem, it was the way I was displaying the color as you explained. Great explanation by the way.

Comment: @nico.user - Great! Glad that helped. :-)